# cannot install zoom on kali

Tags: kali-linux, package-management, zoom

I am trying to install zoom, yet this is the log.

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zoom' instead of './zoom_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zoom : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installable
        Depends: libegl1-mesa but it is not installable
```

This was a partial installation of kali, i didn't even have desktop environment when i first installed it. I installed `xfce desktop environment` even after the installation.

I know I am missing some headers, but how to adjust them?
Or how to fix this error, i research through search engines yet always failed.

Edit: tried install package alone

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
[sudo] password for kali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You should try to install the said packages manually, note the error, and try to resolve that instead.  No messing with Zoom will allow you to get those packages...

Comment: Don't install Zoom on Kali. Leave Kali as its intent: a security and pentesting distribution, and use a more general distro for zoom

Comment: Yes, we really cannot stress this enough: Kali is not a regular operating system and it should not be used as a regular operating system. Zoom has no business being installed on a Kali system. Kali is a tool for professional security experts, if you want Zoom, use a normal OS instead. Please read https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ and [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360)

Comment: Sorry. But i dont use my only OS on one specific "purpose" neither am I limited to. Also no,  I will keep my kali. Dislikers are haters. Don't keep this tag on the site if you have a problem like this

Answer (score 1):

A snap is available, you can install it through:

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

[How to install snap on Kali Docs](https://www.kali.org/docs/tools/snap/)